# Deploying SuiteScript against all transaction record types

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Is there a way to deploy a SuiteScript against all transaction record types? (other than creating a separate deployment for each type of transaction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy to all records and then put an if statement if nlapiGetRecord() is one a transaction type.

```
var txnTypes = ['salesorder','invoice','purchaseordet'];
if(txnTypes.indexOf(nlapiGetRecord()!=-1) { //code goes here; }
```

Either way is 50/50 on which is easier.  I would say the deployments would be best because it don't run on the other record.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy to all transaction record types and then apply a conditional in your code like this:

```
var recordType = nlapiGetRecordType();
if(recordType != 'salesorder' && recordType != 'purchaseorder'){
    return; //Exit
}

//Continue code here.
```